# How to display wordpress product images based on product id(woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress

i have just working woocommerce plugin(wordpress).i have products price and name,but i not get product image,its my ajax funcition 
ajax.php file is blow there,i want product image.i worked now products details add to cart page only and also display product current price and name but i not get image.

ajax function to redirect ajax.php

**first file ajax.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function() {
      var val = $('#mce').val();
      var id = $('#p_id').val();
      var name = $('#pro_name').val();

        $.ajax ({
            url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bootsgrid/ajax.php",
            data: { val : val, id : id, p_name : name },
            success: function( result ) {
               // window.location.href=window.location;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**second file ajax.php**

```
     <?php
        $productID=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $price=$_REQUEST['val'];
        $post_name=$_REQUEST['p_name'];

        require('../../../wp-load.php' );
        $img_url = $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($productID), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

        //print_r($img_url);exit;

            global $woocommerce;

            $my_post = array(
              'post_title'    => $post_name,
              'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
              'post_status'   => 'publish',
              'post_author'   => 1,
              'post_type'     =>'product'
            );
             $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'numberposts' => -1,
           'post_status' => null,
           'post_parent' => $productID
          );
            $attachments = get_posts( $args );

            // Insert the post into the database
            $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );


        $attachmentID = $product_ID;


            add_action('add_attachment', function( $product_ID ) {
          if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Product' ) ) return; // if no WooCommerce do nothing

          // an attachment was jus saved, first of all get the file name
          $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachmentID, 'full' );
          $filename = pathinfo( $src[0], PATHINFO_FILENAME );

          // now let's see if exits a product with the sku that match filename
          $args = array(
            'meta_key' => '_sku',
            'meta_value' => $filename,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => '1' // assuming sku is unique get only one post
          );
          $prods = get_posts( $args );
          if ( ! empty($prods) ) {

            // ok we have a match, exists a product having sku that match filename
            $product = array_pop( $prods );

            // set the thumbnail for the product
            set_post_thumbnail( $product, $attachmentID );

            // now "attach" the post to the product setting 'post_parent'
            $attachment = get_post( $attachmentID );
            $attachment->post_parent =$attachments[0]->ID;
            wp_update_post( $attachment );
          }
        });

            if ( $product_ID ){
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', $price );
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', $price );
              add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );

              //Getting error on this line.
              $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );

            echo "Success";`enter code here`
            }


        ?>
```

Comment: Product id get this function

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dev_designs_show_sku', 5 );
function dev_designs_show_sku(){
    global $product;

Comment: what is your ajax reponse??

Comment: actually my task is product price user can change and update.so my ajax get reponse sucess

Comment: instead o ajax test by include same file

Comment: if you are not include reponse url then how its work